# CSS Footer width

Tags: css, drupal, web, footer

I have been using CSS for only a few weeks now. I am using Drupal to recreate a website. I am having trouble with the footer, it will not extend to fit the screen (like the one on stackoverflow). I want to be able to zoom out and it will extend across the whole site.

I have been looking around the web now for about two days trying to figure this out, at this point I have no more ideas to try.

My site is currently on a DEV server so I have access to all the files. The file I think I need to edit is layout.css but if it is in another file please let me know.

```
    /*
*   site-specific layout statements
*/
/*  Structure
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

body,html{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: #17293d url(../img/backgrounds/main_bg.gif);
}

#totalContainer{
    //margin-top:10px;
    //margin-bottom:10px;
}

.width_1#totalContainer{
    width:1038px;
}

.width_2#totalContainer{
    width:978px;
}

#topBar{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#topBarContainer{
    margin:15px auto 15px auto;
}

.width_1#topBarContainer{
    width:1038px;
}

.width_2#topBarContainer{
    width:978px;
}

#topBarLink{ /* top toggle bar */
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
}

#topBarLink a{ /* top toggle bar */
    float:left;
    margin-left:48.5%; /* make it block level and try to center it without javascript..*/
    padding:15px 10px 5px 10px;
}

#topBarLink.withoutTopRegion a{ /* makes space in case we don't have any element in the top Region */
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

#top{ /* upper part of the template */
    float:left;
    width:101.2%;
    height: 84px;
    position:relative;
    /* margin-bottom:10px; */
    /* background: #black; */
}

#topUtility{
    position:absolute;
    top:13px;
    right:18px;
}

#logo-container{ /* image logo container */
    float:left;
    height:150px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#title-slogan{ /* site title and slogan container */
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#site-title,
#site-slogan{ 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#search{ /* theme search box */
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top: 30px;
}

#search div{ /* search button inline */
    display: inline;
}

//#pageBorder{ /* makes the border */
    //float: left;
//}

.ie7 #pageBorder{ /* for IE7 */
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*#contentWrapper{ /* wraps content */
/*  float: left;
    padding:15px 5px 15px 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* follows the z-index order of primary menu and advertise (to solve ie7 z-index BUG )*/
/*}*/

.breadcrumb{ /* breadcrumb */
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    margin:0px 10px 15px 10px;
}

#footer{ /* site footer*/
    margin-top: 25px;
    /* padding-bottom:60px; */
    float: left;
/*  width: 100%;*/
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#000000;
    display: block;
}

#navigation-footer{ /* site footer*/
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:#000000;
}

#bottomUtility{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}

/* utility menu */

.utility ul.menu{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:square;
}

.utility ul.menu li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 4px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:square;
}

.utility ul.menu li a{
    padding-right:8px;
    list-style:square;
}

.utility ul.menu li:after{
    content:"|";
    list-style:square;
}


/*  Look & Feel
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

body.marinelli{
    background: #17293d url(../img/backgrounds/body.gif);
    /* background: #000; */
    height:125px;
}

#topBar,#topBarLink,#topBarLink a{ /* top toggle bar */
    //background:#054b81;
    background:#101518;
}

#topBarLink a{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.outsidecontent{
    color:white;
}

#site-title,
#site-slogan{
    font-weight: bold;      
}

#site-title{
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height:0.8em;
}

#site-slogan {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}

#pageBorder{ /* border of the whole site */ 
    //border:10px solid #054b81;
    //border:10px solid #0c0c0c;
}

#pageBorder.noborder{ /* when we don't have the advertise region */ 
    border-top:0px;
}

#contentWrapper{
    //background: #17293d url(../img/backgrounds/main_bg.gif);

}

.breadcrumb { /* breadcrumb */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.utility{ /* utility menu */
    font-size:0.9em;
    //text-transform:uppercase;
    list-style:square;
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you (I can has markup?), but there are multiple elements with hard coded widths:  `.width_1#totalContainer`, `.width_2#totalContainer`, etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yx9JM/

Comment: BTW, your fiddle has multiple instances of attempting to comment out specific lines of CSS with double forward slashes (`//`), but only full C style comments (`/* */`) are valid for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a table being used for layout purposes.  Tables are normally only meant to be used for displaying tabular data, not layout.  The default behavior of tables is to shrink to its content (ie. if your content is small, it won't expand the full width of the page).

If you can't modify the markup, all you should need to add is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yx9JM/1/

```
#footer table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick, thank you and everyone else who posted a reply. I will also be fixing the commenting.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've found that you need to set the width of the Body of the page to 100% in order to allow the child element(footer) to extend to 100%. So try doing this:

```
body,html{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width: 100%;
background: #17293d url(../img/backgrounds/main_bg.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a shell that is 'width:100%;` and then an inner element that is centered.

HTML

```
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
  width:100%;
  padding:2em 0;
  background:#d0d0d0;
  border-top:5px solid #000;
}
footer ul {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: And if you are getting small gaps around items, you can do what LukeP said or use a reset.css I use http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and there are plenty more options if you search for them.